Using SUMPRODUCT involving a column which contains empty values coming from an IF(...; ...; "")
Let's say we have this Excel sheet:

A column containing 1 ; 2 ; 3  (i.e. only 3 rows)
B column containing =IF(COUNT(A1)>0;1/A1^2;"")   recopied in B1:B100. Therefore only 3 cells will be non-empty, and the remaining ones won't contain #DIV/0!: they will be empty thanks to the IF COUNT > 0 condition
another cell containing =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100;B1:B100): it works: 1.8333333...
another cell containing =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100;B1:B100 - 5): it doesn't work: since the B column contains a mix of empty cells and numbers, B1:B100 - 5 isn't understood.

In this last example, how to compute the sum of the products a_i * (b_i - 5), for each non-empty row, with SUMPRODUCT?
I also tried with N(...) without success.

If you did want to try and use N(), there is a trick to it. You have to put
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100,N(+B1:B100)-5)

Don't ask me why.

Really interesting @TomSharpe! I thought it would work also with N(0+B1:B100), but no! Strange trick, but effective!

How did you find this cheat code?

Using Excel N function with arrays. Nice to see one of your old questions dredged up @Tom :-)

@Basj there are 91 functions in Excel which needs to add + or -- or 1* or /1 before or after, you can find the full list here: Check

@MayukhBhattacharya Are you sure it's not 92, since the N function is not in your list yet? ;)

Another trick; You could simply add a leading 0:

Formula in D1:
  =SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100,(0&B1:B100)-5)


"" - 5 throws a #VALUE! error since you can't subtract 5 from a string. This can be handled using IFERROR:
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100;IFERROR(B1:B100-5;0))


Alternately, use =IFERROR(1/A1^2;0) in cells B1:B100 and apply a custom number format 0;-0;;@, which will hide the zeroes. Then your SUMPRODUCT will work as expected.

Good idea, thanks @BigBen! Also, do you see a better/simpler way than =IF(COUNT(A1)>0;1/A1^2;"") to only show the B column items that have a corresponding A column item? (NB: A elements are always nonzero) Also, such that the SUMPRODUCT in column C doesn't require this IFERROR?

Return 0 instead of "" and then format the cells in B1:B100 with the custom format 0;-0;;@, which will hide the zeroes.

This is without the IF COUNT > 0 condition: https://i.sstatic.net/ZIQEbUmS.png

I think you can post your last comment as a second solution in the answer @BigBen :)

More generally @BigBen, what is the standard practice to prepopulate a column with a formula (B1:B100) which makes use of the A column, and have each element of col B displayed if and only if the corresponding element in col A is non-empty? TL;DR: prepopulate B but avoid this effect: https://i.sstatic.net/ZIQEbUmS.png  I am sure there is a solution for this general problem, but I don't find the right keyword to make a search :)

Your current approach is fine. You could also use FILTER if your Excel version supports dynamic arrays.

You mean the "IF COUNT > 0" approach is common to only compute certain elements, and return "" otherwise?

Generally the construct returning "" is common. In your case you need numeric output for further analysis, not blank strings.




B
C




=IF(ISNUMBER(A1:A100);1/A1:A100^2;"")
=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A100;IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B100);  B1:B100-5;0))



